# transfer photo from ubuntu to iphone

Tags: iphone

My pc is ubuntu 14.04. My iphone is ios9.

When I connect iphone with my pc via USB, I can copy any photo in my iphone (under directory DCIM) to my PC, then I'm able to open the photo on my PC.

However, when I copy a photo from the PC to the DCIM folder of my iphone, the photo is not show inside the icon "Photos" in iphone. That is, I cannot access the copied photo on my iphone. Any ideas?

Comment: Using Google Drive app on both of your Ubuntu and iPhone to access or download your photos among of them may be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As for now, only PTP photo access works with iOS 9 and later. Simply sorry to say but Camera/Photo Synchronization is not available with iOS 9 through libimobiledevice library. But you can upload photos to icloud library from your computer and later access them on your iPhone. That's what I'm doing

Answer (score -2):

Iphone does not connect well with latest ubuntu version via USB cable.
I use an App on Iphone: Wifi Photo (there are a lot of other apps) and I can backup my photos via Wifi